# How to set up registration with email (no password) and display name in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to set up authentication with email (used to receive a link) and display name only, without password. However, from the documentation I only found createUserWithEmailAndPassword. I tried `auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail`, which enables me to sign in, but it can't create new user in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for email link authentication. See the [Firebase documentation for email link authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth) for full details.

There won't automatically be a display name with this form of authentication, but you can set the display name of your choice in the user profile. See the [Firebase documentation on updating a user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) for details on that.

Comment: The doc shows how to sign in with email. Is it the same as registering with email?

Comment: The link I sent shows `auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail`, which is separate from the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` which you called out. If it doesn't do what you need, please update your question to show what you tried.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I updated the question. My problem is the function `auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail` is for signing in, can it create a new user in the database?

Comment: If the user clicks the sign-in link and they're new to the system, a Firebase Authentication profile will automatically be created for them.